# Upload internet picture as it was on your local computer

Tags: php, codeigniter

Is there a way to tell php to handle the remote picture for example: http://pic.jpg as an ordinary file being uploaded through the upload form and save it in `$_FILES` as

```
array (size=5)
   'name' => string 'pic.jpg' (length=18)
   'type' => string 'image/jpeg' (length=10)
   'tmp_name' => string 'C:\Program Files\wamp\tmp\php3018.tmp' (length=37)
   'error' => int 0
   'size' => int 879394
```

I need to handle remote picture as a local picture so I can run it through Codeigniters upload library, which will resize it and store it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get the contents of the file, put the contents of the file(if needed) and use that file path..

```
$pic = file_get_contents('http://pic.jpg');
file_put_contents('/path/to/save/pic.jpg',$pic);
```

or if you don't want to save the image, then use `imagecreatefromstring()`

```
$pic = file_get_contents('http://pic.jpg');
$image = imagecreatefromstring($pic);
```

I'm fairly sure codeigniters upload class doesn't do any image manipulation..

Comment: It does, you can save `$config['new_image']` and set new `$config['width']`, I am simply trying to pass online picture in the `do_upload()` method

Comment: no, there really is nothing in the Upload class that changes the image dimensions after uploading and before saving... honestly there just isn't. https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/blob/develop/system/libraries/Upload.php

Comment: Sorry, I was looking the wrong method, there is a resize function in `image_lib`

Comment: yes, so you do not need to run it through do_upload do you?  just use the image_lib on the saved image, or the generated image from string.

Comment: "generated image from string" ? How do I put that remote image in a string format and then put it through `resize`?

Comment: well looking at the Image_lib in CI, you have to do it from a saved image, so i don't think you can do it that way.. so just use my first snipped, and then initialise the Image_Lib using the saved image path then do whatever you need to do

Answer (score 0):

What if you downloaded it first with php using this:

```
    copy('http://anything.com/image.jpg', 'yourdrive/folder/anyname.jpg');
```

*you must have allow_url_fopen set to true

And then you can handle it in any way you want.

Comment: "And then you can handle it in any way you want." Right, how would that be? I need to automaticly upload that file after though the `do_upload()` method

Comment: Then you can upload it via [ftp](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ftp-put.php) for example. The destination path to copy() can be in your server ofc. In that way you have no need for upload.

Comment: What I ment to say, I need that file to be processed as it was uploaded via html form, meaning I need data stored in $_FILE function in the right format i posted in my question

Comment: Well the only way i can think is after saving the image in your server extracting the data you want and putting them in $_FILE or wherever you want name and tempname is easy to get them via the path you already know, for image type you can use exif_imagetype() and for the size you can use getimagesize().

Answer (score 0):

```
$imageUrl = "http://anything.com/image.jpg";
$contents = file_get_contents(trim($imageUrl));
file_put_contents('/path/to/save/', $contents);
```